# Why two event listeners are triggered instead of one?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have element which has two event listeners that are triggered depending of his class name. During click event, his className is changing, and this another class has its own different event listener. Two events should be triggered alternately by every click.

During first click listener calls function editClub, but all the next clicks calls two functions. I don't know why that removed-class-event is triggered. Maybe its because after each event function callListeners is executed, and there are multiple listeners on one object? But should be triggered just one. Later I wrote removeListeners function which remove all existing listeners and put her to call just before callListeners function. But then just editClub function is executed by every click. What's wrong with my code?

```
function callListeners() 
{
    if ( document.getElementsByClassName('editBtn') )
    {
        let x = document.getElementsByClassName('editBtn');
        for ( let i = 0; i < x.length; i++ )
        {
            x[i].addEventListener('click', editClub);
        }
    }

    if ( document.getElementsByClassName('saveBtn') )
    {
        let x = document.getElementsByClassName('saveBtn');
        for ( let i = 0; i < x.length; i++ )
        {
            x[i].addEventListener('click', saveClub);
        }
    }
}

function editClub(event) 
{
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setAttribute('src','img/\icon_save.png');
    this.setAttribute('class','saveBtn');
    //removeListeners();           <-- here I placed removeListeners function
    callListeners();
}

function saveClub(event) 
{
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setAttribute('src', 'img/\icon_edit.png');
    this.setAttribute('class', 'editBtn');
     //removeListeners();              <-- here I placed removeListeners function
    callListeners();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not removing the classes when the click event happens so after the first click the element has both classes.

Comment: It looks like that but why? setAttribute function should override all the classes in class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Just changing an element's class does not change the event listeners that were setup on it previously. They will still be there unless you explicitly remove them, or the elements themselves are destroyed. And you get multiple calls because you keep adding new listeners without removing the old ones.

You could on each click remove the old listener and add the new listener

```
function editClub(){
  this.removeEventListener("click",editClub);
  this.addEventListener("click",saveClub);
}
function saveClub(){
  this.removeEventListener("click",saveClub);
  this.addEventListener("click",editClub);
}
```

But that is a bit tedious. Instead you can setup a [delegated event listener](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) on a static parent like `document`. Doing so allows for a single event listener which will be called when either button is clicked. Then in that listener you can check the element's class, and execute the appropriate function for it:

```
function clubAction(event){
  //get a reference to the element clicked
  var element = event.target;

  //call the appropriate function
  //or just do the work here
  if(element.classList.contains("editClub")){
    editClub.call(element,event);
  } else if(element.classList.contains("saveClub")) {
    saveClub.call(element,event);
  }
}

document.addEventListener("click",clubAction);
```

[classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) is a property that lets you get,set,remove, and other operations for the classes of the element.

---

Demo

```js
function clubAction(event) {
  var element = event.target;
  if (element.classList.contains("editClub")) {
    editClub.call(element,event);
  } else if (element.classList.contains("saveClub")) {
    saveClub.call(element,event);
  }
}

document.addEventListener("click", clubAction);

function editClub(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.classList.remove('editClub');
  this.classList.add('saveClub');
  this.innerText = "Save";
}

function saveClub(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.classList.add('editClub');
  this.classList.remove('saveClub');
  this.innerText = "Edit";
}
```

```css
.saveClub {
  background:#0F0;
}

.editClub {
  background:#FF0;
}
```

```html
<button class="saveClub">Save</button>
<button class="editClub">Edit</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive reply and explanation about delegated listeners. I didin't knew that method before but its great. I have many listeners on elements, that are dynamically added or removed. Now its much more handy.